# access_token and id_token returned by openId Connect for different tabs of same app

Tags: openid-connect

I have integrated OIDC library with my React Js single page application.

If I login in 1 tab through OIDC and open the same app in multiple tabs of browser, will the access_token and id_token returned by oidc remain same for all the tabs or they are different for each tab?

p.s- I have implemented single sign on (SSO) and it's working perfectly.
I'm happy to share additional code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Access token will be stored somewhere in your browser and your client should be handling it to send same access token even if you access the app in new url. You have to look into odic implementation in UI. Same applies with id token.

Answer (score 0):

Tokens in SPAs should really only be stored in memory and not in HTML5 storage, as a security best practice. See the [browser in memory scenarios](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/concepts/token-storage).

This leads to [code like this](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.websample2/blob/master/spa/src/plumbing/oauth/authenticator.ts).

This means different tabs will get different tokens, and each tab will do its own redirect. Of course, not everyone will like this from a usability viewpoint and there are trade offs with security here.